# SWRevealViewController : Make Starting Background View Grey with custom animations

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller, setbackground

I am fairly new to iOS. I tried to look this up but couldn't find a definite answer to the following.

I have a SWRevealViewController to handle side menu bar from my FirstPage.

When the SWReveal appears after clicking btn_Menu (or by swiping left) I want the FirstPage to become grey and unusable.

I see that in FirstPage we have to do the following:

```
[btn_Menu addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I need to change the revealToggle method somehow, or write a new selector in FirstPage which darkens it first, and then calls revealToggle ? I am unsure what's the best and easiest way to get this done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: in before page load u need the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your FirstPage viewDidLoad do this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
SWRevealViewController *  revealController=[[SWRevealViewController alloc]init];
    revealController = [self revealViewController];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
       revealController.delegate=self;
    [revealController panGestureRecognizer];

    [revealController tapGestureRecognizer];
    [btnSideMenu addTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
```

After that add this delegate method of SWRevealViewController in to your FirstPage.

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{
    if (revealController.frontViewPosition == FrontViewPositionRight)
    {
        UIView *lockingView = [UIView new];
        lockingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:revealController action:@selector(revealToggle:)];
        [lockingView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [lockingView addGestureRecognizer:revealController.panGestureRecognizer];
        [lockingView setTag:1000];
        [revealController.frontViewController.view addSubview:lockingView];


        lockingView.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];

        NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(lockingView);

        [revealController.frontViewController.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[lockingView]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        [revealController.frontViewController.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[lockingView]|"
                                                 options:0
                                                 metrics:nil
                                                   views:viewsDictionary]];
        [lockingView sizeToFit];
    }
    else
        [[revealController.frontViewController.view viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer, but this didn't change anything..

Could it be because the way my Firstpage.h is defined ?

    @interface FirstPage : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate>

Comment: have you set delegate of SWRevealViewController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: I tried simple NSLog inside the function you provided, it seems it's never being called.. :-/

Comment: set this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions   revealController.delegate = self;

Comment: I actually don't have a revealController for AppDelegate.h, do I need to create that property as well ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for so many questions, I am beginning to learn all this. I just moved all your code into FirstPage.m and it works :).